# How to let table row cells resize independently without affecting one another

Tags: html, html-table, resize

I have a html table inside a asp.net page. it has a single tr and it contains two td cells. These cells contain whole page content. First td contains a simple form. and second td contains a SSRS report viewer. When the page loads first td loads fine. after submitting the form the page loads the report. When the report loads the second td resizes along with the first td. so the content of the form change. following is my sample of my code.

```
<table class="Vardena_b_8_n_copy" style="width: 100%" cellspacing="0" 
    cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; height:200px;" valign="top">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%" valign="top">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table
```

Answer (score 0):

in my expirience, if you use inline style can cause that kind of problem. try to use external stylee